# Admin warning 0000

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've posted this over on [forum.joomla.org](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=963520&p=3531603) but don't know which user group is more active.

I am new to joomla but have extensive experience (10+ years) with other cms.

Client gave me a kickstart .jpa file to move their site to a new host server. The kickstart seemed to run fine but every page of admin has yellow warning box with "00000, ,". [image]

The front end of the site on the new host only says "Error" but with almost a whole screen of html before. I can see joomla code (ie `<jdoc:include type="head" />`) when I view frontend source.

I've tried turning on debugging in System > Global Configuration > System tab but there was no additional info.

Can anyone suggest somewhere to start looking?

Thanks
Amanda

Comment: In host cpanel I rolled php back to 5.6 and at least it's showing the site front end.

Comment: tail error_log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

00000 is an SQL error usually, and the fact that debug doesn't show anything further suggests that it's coming from outside of php land. I'm guessing that you're trying to use pdo, switch to mysqli and then it should work.

Comment: Yes, switching to mysqli (Global Configuration > Server > Database Type) removed the warning. I wonder why it wasn't set on the original site? Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: @jamesgarrett Do you work at preflight?  I am confused, there is another garrett at that agency in Melbourne.  I wanted to ask you to fill out our 5-minute JoomlaDay survey: https://joomladay.org.au/program/have-your-say but I couldn't find a contact email for you.

Comment: Indeed, I work at Preflight.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the `errorInfo` data.  The good news is that what is being displayed actually means NO errors.

When `errorInfo` serves up: `array('00000', null, null)` everything is functioning flawlessly ...or at least one of your queries ran flawlessly.  You see, it may serve up the last successful query and not express a subsequent error.

Anyhow, you don't really want to see that mess so the solution should be to apply this setting to your pdo:

```
setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
```

The easiest place to add this attribute is immediately after your connection (where ever you are doing that).

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Here are a few relevant StackOverflow posts:

- [PDO not inserting - error code 00000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39830887/2943403)
- [PHP PDO. error number '00000' when query is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11813911/2943403)
- [PDO SQL-state “00000” but still error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11519966/2943403)
- [After creating table it shows this Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10562735/2943403)